# Loop with incremental value based on user input

Tags: java, loops, increment

I have a task about incremental values in a loop based on user input.

The task is that the following lines are generated in the console

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

And the amount of lines are decided by user input. I.e. if the user types in 2 it gives the following output:

```
*
**
```

My current code is:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
public class loop1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int current_line = 0;
        String input_line = showInputDialog("type here ");
        int target_line = Integer.parseInt(input_line);
        while (current_line != target_line){
            String sign = "*";
            System.out.println(sign);
            current_line ++;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get the number of asterisks (*) to increase for every time it runs. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: (It will be easier to start with `for(;;)` loops in this problem.)

Comment: I would really recommend looking at this http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Looping/NestedFor.htm this is what I would use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need two loops here, but you only have one. You have a `while` loop to print out the asterisks, but you also need a loop to increment the number of asterisks printed out each time.

Some pseudocode might look like:

```
For (int i = 1 to whatever value the user entered):
    For (int j = 1 to i):
        Print an asterisk
```

Actual code would look like:

```
int numLines = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("type here "));
for(int numAsterisks = 0; numAsterisks < numLines; numAsterisks++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numAsterisks; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println(); // Start a new line
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a nested loop. Each iteration of the outer loop (which is the loop you already have) would print a single row, and each iteration of the inner loop would print a single asterisk for the current row.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it simpler by using nested for loops. Modify your loop to:

```
for (int i=0;i<target_line;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You print everytime one '*'-sign.
You don't necessarily need two loops. You can place the sign outside of the loop and you can add an asterisk every iteration with string.concat("*"). Concatenating actually means combining two strings into one, so you actually combine the sign from the previous iteration with a new sign.

```
int current_line = 0;
String input_line = showInputDialog("type here ");
int target_line = Integer.parseInt(input_line);
String sign = "*";
while (current_line != target_line){
    sign.concat("*");
    System.out.println(sign);
    current_line ++;
}
```